# NHibernate connect Oracle The element 'id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'column'

Tags: .net, oracle, nhibernate

i face to error when try to configuration NHibernate connect to Oracle:

> NhbHelper.CUSTOMER.hbm.xml(6,8): XML validation error: The element 'id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'column' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

error happend when i try to add assembly

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.AddAssembly("NhbHelper");
sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

my CUSTOMER.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using System; 


namespace NhbHelper.Customer {

    public class CUSTOMER {
        public CUSTOMER() { }
        public virtual long CUSTOMER_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string CUSTOMER_CODE { get; set; }
        public virtual string CUSTOMER_NAME { get; set; }
        public virtual string SHOP_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string COUNTRY { get; set; }
        public virtual string AREA_CODE { get; set; }
        public virtual string STREET { get; set; }
        public virtual string HOUSENUMBER { get; set; }
        public virtual string PHONE { get; set; }
        public virtual System.Nullable<System.DateTime> CREATE_DATE { get; set; }
        public virtual System.Nullable<System.DateTime> UPDATE_DATE { get; set; }
        public virtual string POSTAL_CODE { get; set; }
        public virtual string CONTACT_PERSON { get; set; }
        public virtual string TAX_CODE { get; set; }
        public virtual string MOBILEPHONE { get; set; }
        public virtual string LOCATION { get; set; }
        public virtual long CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual long LOYALTY { get; set; }
        public virtual string CREATE_USER { get; set; }
        public virtual string UPDATE_USER { get; set; }
        public virtual string DISLAY { get; set; }
        public virtual System.Nullable<System.DateTime> LAST_APPROVE_ORDER { get; set; }
        public virtual System.Nullable<System.DateTime> LAST_ORDER { get; set; }
        public virtual System.Nullable<long> STATUS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here my CUSTOMER.hbm.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="NhbHelper" namespace="NhbHelper.Customer" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="CUSTOMER" table="CUSTOMER" lazy="true" >
    <id name="CUSTOMER_ID">
      <generator class="identity" />
      <column name="CUSTOMER_ID" sql-type="NUMBER"  />
    </id>
    <property name="CUSTOMER_CODE">
      <column name="CUSTOMER_CODE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="CUSTOMER_NAME">
      <column name="CUSTOMER_NAME" sql-type="NVARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="SHOP_ID">
      <column name="SHOP_ID" sql-type="NVARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="COUNTRY">
      <column name="COUNTRY" sql-type="NVARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="AREA_CODE">
      <column name="AREA_CODE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="STREET">
      <column name="STREET" sql-type="NVARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="HOUSENUMBER">
      <column name="HOUSENUMBER" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="PHONE">
      <column name="PHONE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="CREATE_DATE">
      <column name="CREATE_DATE" sql-type="DATE" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="UPDATE_DATE">
      <column name="UPDATE_DATE" sql-type="DATE" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="POSTAL_CODE">
      <column name="POSTAL_CODE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="CONTACT_PERSON">
      <column name="CONTACT_PERSON" sql-type="NVARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="TAX_CODE">
      <column name="TAX_CODE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="MOBILEPHONE">
      <column name="MOBILEPHONE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="LOCATION">
      <column name="LOCATION" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID">
      <column name="CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID" sql-type="NUMBER" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="LOYALTY">
      <column name="LOYALTY" sql-type="NUMBER" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="CREATE_USER">
      <column name="CREATE_USER" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="UPDATE_USER">
      <column name="UPDATE_USER" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="DISLAY">
      <column name="DISLAY" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="LAST_APPROVE_ORDER">
      <column name="LAST_APPROVE_ORDER" sql-type="DATE" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="LAST_ORDER">
      <column name="LAST_ORDER" sql-type="DATE" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="STATUS">
      <column name="STATUS" sql-type="NUMBER" not-null="false" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the column tag on your mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="NhbHelper" namespace="NhbHelper.Customer" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="CUSTOMER" table="CUSTOMER" lazy="true" >
    <id name="CUSTOMER_ID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="CUSTOMER_CODE">
      <column name="CUSTOMER_CODE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="CUSTOMER_NAME">
      <column name="CUSTOMER_NAME" sql-type="NVARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="SHOP_ID">
      <column name="SHOP_ID" sql-type="NVARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="COUNTRY">
      <column name="COUNTRY" sql-type="NVARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="AREA_CODE">
      <column name="AREA_CODE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="STREET">
      <column name="STREET" sql-type="NVARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="HOUSENUMBER">
      <column name="HOUSENUMBER" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="PHONE">
      <column name="PHONE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="CREATE_DATE">
      <column name="CREATE_DATE" sql-type="DATE" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="UPDATE_DATE">
      <column name="UPDATE_DATE" sql-type="DATE" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="POSTAL_CODE">
      <column name="POSTAL_CODE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="CONTACT_PERSON">
      <column name="CONTACT_PERSON" sql-type="NVARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="TAX_CODE">
      <column name="TAX_CODE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="MOBILEPHONE">
      <column name="MOBILEPHONE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="LOCATION">
      <column name="LOCATION" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID">
      <column name="CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID" sql-type="NUMBER" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="LOYALTY">
      <column name="LOYALTY" sql-type="NUMBER" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="CREATE_USER">
      <column name="CREATE_USER" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="UPDATE_USER">
      <column name="UPDATE_USER" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="DISLAY">
      <column name="DISLAY" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="LAST_APPROVE_ORDER">
      <column name="LAST_APPROVE_ORDER" sql-type="DATE" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="LAST_ORDER">
      <column name="LAST_ORDER" sql-type="DATE" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="STATUS">
      <column name="STATUS" sql-type="NUMBER" not-null="false" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks @Euclides but when i remove the column as you said, it's thow new exeption:
NhbHelper.CUSTOMER.hbm.xml(4,6): XML validation error: The element 'class' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'property' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of possible elements expected: 'meta, subselect, cache, synchronize, comment, tuplizer, id, composite-id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

Comment: can you show your mapping after removing the column tag? I edited my answer to show the final mapping.

Comment: by the way, can you tell me what operator is: '=>'  example in this mapping code:                     
return Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(persistenceConfigurer)
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
        AutoMap.AssemblyOf<User>()
            .Override<User>(map=> map.HasMany(user=> user.Transactions).KeyColumn("Buyer_id"))
            .Override<User>(map => map.HasMany(user => user.Transactions).KeyColumn("Seller_id"))                
        ))
    .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
    .BuildSessionFactory();